# Media9 3D PDF - isolate view by sub-part?

Tags: pdftex, 3d, media9

I have embedded a .u3d file into a pdf using Media9 package not too many issues. Additional views have also been set up within an auxiliary views file.

Just wanted to know if we are able to isolate by sub-part within a part? [image: package documentation snippet attached].

The embedded .u3d is a CAD assembly where the main part then contains sub-parts for assembly components.

E.g. PART 1 in the model tree = box1. Sub-parts: face1,face2,face3 and face4. Am I able to make only face4 within box1 transparent?

Hope this is making sense. English as a second language.

Comment: This easiest method is to manipulate the part in Acrobat Reader and to re-export the current view via the context menu (right mouseclick). Then copy and paste the view from the console into your views file, finally re-typeset (`pdflatex`) the document.